Change Font Size Autofill PDF using pdf-lib on JS
This works
form.getTextField("name").setText("John Doe"); 

// This does not work
form.getTextField("name").setFontSize(12).updatedField.setText("John Doe");

The second line is giving me
Error: No /DA (default appearance) entry found for field: name
    at new MissingDAEntryError

I dunno how to fix this? How can I set the setFontSize(12) or is there a way that I can change the size of the autofill box height? that would solve it too.

From the docs: https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdftextfield
=> setFontSize method:

This method depends upon the existence of a default appearance (/DA) string. If this field does not have a default appearance string, or that string does not contain a font size (via the Tf operator), then this method will throw an error.
But I still don't know how to set the default appearance... Anyone?


I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091490/pdf-lib-how-to-add-custom-font
